# Keras: Specify shape of output correctly (for Convolutional Autoencoder)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

In Keras I have the model

```
input_img = Input(shape=(150, 360, 3))

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is autoencoder.layers[6].output_shape = (None, 19, 45, 8)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)                                      #10
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)                                     
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

The final shape is

```
autoencoder.layers[13].output_shape
(None, 152, 360, 3)
```

This is not surprising from the setup of the layers and the fact that I can only use integers for the size for the layers `MaxPooling2D` and `UpSampling2D`. But how can I deal with this?

How do I get back to the shape of `(150, 360, 3)`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the height dimension (150) is not divisible by 8.

**SOLUTION 1**:
It might not be the best solution, but you could add a [Cropping2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#cropping2d) layer after the last UpSampling2D layer:

```
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Cropping2D(cropping=(1, 0))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

By using this operation you are basically telling the model to ignore the first and last rows of the last UpSampling2D's output.

**SOLUTION 2**: You could also use [ZeroPadding2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d) pad the input image to make it have height 152:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(150, 360, 3))
x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 0))(input_img)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

In this way, the height dimension is divisible by 8.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I also identified the problem. The solution is what bugs me ;-). This sound like a solution, but seems not ideal yet. How about a Dense layer that has the right number of output neurons? Maybe in the middle, after the encoding?

Comment: I think that a Dense layer in the bottleneck would not help (you would still have the same problem, because there isn't any integer `x` such that `x*8=150`). I think that cropping in the decoder is not a big deal (the network would figure out  by itself that the discarded neurons are useless). I added another possible solution, in case it looks more appealing to you. If you are not satisfied with any of them, I believe you should necessarily change the architecture.